# How to convert Oracle LISTAGG() function to SQL Server using Stuff()

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, t-sql, concatenation

I am trying to convert this Oracle script to T-SQL:

Oracle code:

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,
       'BDS: ' || LISTAGG(BD, ' , ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Col5, Col6) || '.' AS BDs
from(Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6,
             to_char(Col7) || '-' || Col8 || '-' || to_char(Col5) || '-' || to_char(Col6) BD
     from TBL1
     order by Col6)
Group BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
```

Sample result:

```
    COl1 | COl2 | COl3 | Col4 | BDS
    Z1   | 1    | 12   | 1    | BDS: 1-M-12-6-1 + 1-M-12-6-2 + 1-M-12-6-3
    Z1   | 1    | 31   | 1    | BDS: 1-M-31-6-5 + 1-M-31-6-6 + 1-M-31-6-7
```

So far I have tried,

```
Select 
    Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,
    'BDS: ' + STUFF (select ' , ' + BD
                     from TBL1
                     group by BD
                     order by Col5, Col6    
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + '.' AS BDS    
from 
    (select 
        Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col7) + '-' + Col8+ '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col5)   + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col6) BD
     from TBL1) A1
Group By 
   Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, BD
```

Result:

```
     COl1 | COl2 | COl3 | Col4 | BDS
     Z1   | 1    | 12   | 1    | BDS: + 1-M-12-6-1 + 1-M-12-6-1 + 1-M-12-6-1......(repeats for more than 100 times)
     Z1   | 1    | 12   | 1    | BDS: + 1-M-12-6-2 + 1-M-12-6-2 + 1-M-12-6-2......(repeats for more than 100 times)
```

Problem:

- `Col3` needs to have unique values
- `BDS` needs to concatenate strings if it's corresponding values in `Col3` is same
- need to remove the first occurrence of `+` from `BDS` column, which I thought the `FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''` would do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, below is the script

```
Select 
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,
'BDS: ' + STUFF (select ' , ' + BD
                 from (select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6,
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col7) + '-' + Col8+ '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col5)   + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col6) BD
                       from TBL1) A1
                 where A1.col1 =A2.col1 and
                       A1.col2 = A2.col2 and
                       A1.col3 = A2.col3 and
                       A1.col4 = A2.col4 and
                       A1.col5 = A2.col5 and
                       A1.col6 = A2.col6
                 order by Col5, Col6    
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + '.' AS BDS    
from 
(select 
    Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col7) + '-' + Col8+ '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col5)   + '-' + CONVERT    (VARCHAR,Col6) BD
     from TBL1) A2
Group By 
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
```